# WhereScape RED Job aborts fails after executing powerShell

Tags: powershell, return-value, wherescape-red

In WhereScape RED I created a Job calling a PowerShellScript as first task.

The Script runs fine but WhereScape RED still fails the job.

How to make the WhereScape Job run fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is NO output on STD OUT prior to printing out 1 to indicate success.

Then you may print additional information on STD OUT

Answer (score 0):

Basic WS RED script STD OUT rules are:

- The first line of expected STD OUT is script status information:
  1 to indicate success,
  -1 to indicate a warning condition (Job execution continues),
  -2 to indicate a handled error occurred (and halt Job),
  -3 to indicate an unhandled error (and halt the Job).
- The second line is the base status message visible in WhereScape RED UI for each task (should be < 255 chars).
- Remaining lines are up to the developer (they end up in audit log/task detailed view).